# How do i delete an item from a Filtered UITableView, without actually deleting it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a UITableView which gets an array of Core Data objects from a FetchedResultsController.
I want to be able to delete an object from the table view using the standard delete button and have the tableview cell fade out like it usually does when an item is deleted, however in my case i am not *actually* deleting the object but marking it as deleted. Eg/ I have an attribute called deleted, so it still exists but appears deleted;

```
obj.deleted = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

Is there such a way to do this so it still appears to work as per a standard delete?

I cant seem to do this without calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` so i am loosing the nice animations that come with the standard delete.

My tableView fetched results controller has a filter so the data in the tableView is filtered;

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
```

is suspect the code i need would go here;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "marking it as deleted in core data" and "so it still appears to work as per a standard delete"?

Comment: Sorry, was hard to explain. I have a BOOL attribute called deleted, which I would like set to `obj.deleted = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];` so the fetched results controller doesn't fetch it. Hope that made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` already has a method `isDeleted`, so a custom attribute `deleted` probably interferes with that method. You could add an attribute `invisible` to your entity and check for

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"invisible == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
```

in the fetched results controller. If you set

```
obj.invisible = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

the object should be removed from the table view. (You might have to save the context, I am not 100% sure right now.)

Comment: Nailed it. Didn't even have to save the context. Just assigned `obj.invisible = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];` and fades out as if it is being deleted. Thanks