# NSManagedObject's @synthesize attribute stays faulted after modifying a relationship

Tags: core-data, dynamic, synthesize

I'm using code derived from Apple's [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) example code. In my class `Appointment` I have a relationship to `Location`. Furthermore I generate a section identifier used by a UITableViewController.

```
@class Location;

@interface Appointment : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * begin;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * end;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Location * location;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sectionIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *primitiveSectionIdentifier;

@end



@implementation Appointment

@synthesize begin = _begin;
@dynamic end;
@dynamic location;
@dynamic primitiveSectionIdentifier;
@dynamic sectionIdentifier;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Transient properties

- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier {

    // Create and cache the section identifier on demand.

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveSectionIdentifier];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    if (!tmp) {
        /*
         Sections are organized by month and year. Create the section identifier as a string representing the number (year * 1000) + month; this way they will be correctly ordered chronologically regardless of the actual name of the month.
         */
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)
                                                   fromDate:[self begin]];
        tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([components year] * 10000) + [components month] * 100 + [components day]];
        [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:tmp];
    }

    return tmp;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Begin setter

- (void)setBegin:(NSDate *)begin
{
    // If the time stamp changes, the section identifier become invalid.
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"begin"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"primitiveSectionIdentifier"];

    _begin = begin;
    [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:nil];

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"begin"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"primitiveSectionIdentifier"];
}

@end
```

---

**The problem**: After altering the location the data stays faulted.
Before modifying `location` the object looks like this:

```
<Appointment: 0x837d570> (entity: Appointment; id: 0x837c900 <x-coredata://83B2187C-00B3-4029-B4C5-4EB69C18FC59/Appointment/p1> ; data: {
    begin = "2013-07-27 16:00:00 +0000";
    end = "2013-07-27 18:00:00 +0000";
    location = "0x837e6c0 <x-coredata://83B2187C-00B3-4029-B4C5-4EB69C18FC59/Location/p1>";
})
```

After altering the property `location`:

```
<Appointment: 0x9b7b1f0> (entity: Appointment; id: 0x9b7ab50 <x-coredata://83B2187C-00B3-4029-B4C5-4EB69C18FC59/Appointment/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

If I relinquish from generating a section identifier and using a `@dynamic` instead of a `@synthesized` property it still works. What's the cause of this and how can I overcome this?

Comment: Is "Appointment" the same as "ReservationModel" ??

Comment: Sorry, my fault due to simplification.

Comment: What do you mean by "After altering the location the data stays faulted" ? A fault is not an error. What exactly does not work? - Note also that attributes of managed objects are not realized by instance variables. `@synthesize begin = _begin;` and `_begin = begin;` is not correct.

Comment: I expected Core Data to load the faulted parts of the object when accessing them (or when printing them in the debugger console). But it doesn't. You're saying that I'm doing it wrong, what's the correct way of generating the value of the properties `begin` and `sectionIdentifier`?

Comment: Yes, when you explicitly access an attribute then it should be loaded.  Perhaps you can show your code and the output. - It should be `@dynamic begin;` and `[self setPrimitiveBegin:begin];` as in the DateSectionTitles sample code.

Comment: Setting `begin` and `location`, saving, and then changing `location`, the following will assign nil to `begin`: `NSDate *begin = appointment.begin;`. Surprisingly, opening the SQLite file shows that `begin` is NOT nil in the persistent store.

Comment: A wild guess: Rename the property "begin" to something else. Some property names cannot be used even if it is not documented (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15700617/1187415 for one example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Martin R** who pointed me in the right direction I've found the problem in my code.

What I didn't know was the fact that Core Data automatically generates additional *primitive* properties for you:

> For example, given an entity with an attribute firstName, Core Data
>   automatically generates firstName, setFirstName:, primitiveFirstName,
>   and setPrimitiveFirstName:. Core Data does this even for entities
>   represented by NSManagedObject. To suppress compiler warnings when you
>   invoke these methods, you should use the Objective-C 2.0 declared
>   properties feature, as described in “Declaration.”
>
> ([Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html))

The fact that I wasn't aware of this leaded me to adopt the example code in a wrong way. The way it works for me is now:

```
@class Location;

@interface Appointment : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * primitiveBegin;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * begin;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * end;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Location * location;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sectionIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *primitiveSectionIdentifier;

@end




@implementation Appointment

@dynamic primitiveBegin;
@dynamic begin;

@dynamic end;
@dynamic location;

@dynamic primitiveSectionIdentifier;
@dynamic sectionIdentifier;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Transient properties

- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier {

    // Create and cache the section identifier on demand.

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveSectionIdentifier];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    if (!tmp) {
        /*
         Sections are organized by month and year. Create the section identifier as a string representing the number (year * 1000) + month; this way they will be correctly ordered chronologically regardless of the actual name of the month.
         */
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)
                                                   fromDate:[self begin]];
        tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([components year] * 10000) + [components month] * 100 + [components day]];
        [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:tmp];
    }

    return tmp;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Begin setter

- (void)setBegin:(NSDate *)begin
{
    // If the time stamp changes, the section identifier become invalid.
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"begin"];
    [self setPrimitiveBegin:begin];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"begin"];

    [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:nil];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Key path dependencies

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSectionIdentifier
{
    // If the value of timeStamp changes, the section identifier may change as well.
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"begin"];
}

@end
```